# How to convert a string to JSON friendly string?

Tags: c#, json, .net-core

I have a string (text) that I would like to convert using a JSON parser so that it is javascript friendly.

In my view page I have some javascript that looks like:

```
var site = {
      strings: {
        addToCart: @someValue,
```

So @someValue should be javascript safe like double quotes, escaped chars if needed etc.

That value @someValue is a string, but it has to be javascript friendly so I want to parse it using JSON.

Does the new System.Text.Json have something?

I tried this:

```
return System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(input).ToString();
```

But this doesnt' work because my text is just a string, not a JSON string.

Is there another way to parse something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules for escaping strings to make them JSON safe are as follows:

- Backspace is replaced with \b
- Form feed is replaced with \f
- Newline is replaced with \n
- Carriage return is replaced with \r
- Tab is replaced with \t
- Double quote is replaced with \"
- Backslash is replaced with \\

And while it's not strictly necessary, any non-web-safe character (i.e. any non-ASCII character) can be converted to its escaped Unicode equivalent to avoid potential encoding issues.

From this, it's pretty straightforward to create your own conversion method:

```
public static string MakeJsonSafe(String s)
{
    var jsonEscaped = s.Replace("\\", "\\\\")
                       .Replace("\"", "\\\"")
                       .Replace("\b", "\\b")
                       .Replace("\f", "\\f")
                       .Replace("\n", "\\n")
                       .Replace("\r", "\\r")
                       .Replace("\t", "\\t");
    var nonAsciiEscaped = jsonEscaped.Select((c) => c >= 127 ? "\\u" + ((int)c).ToString("X").PadLeft(4, '0') : c.ToString());
    return string.Join("", nonAsciiEscaped);
}
```

[DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MmnMQO)

(Like I said, the `nonAsciiEscaped` stage can be omitted as it's not strictly necessary.)

Comment: I wonder if there is a built-in method that does this for us?

Comment: @Blankman I'm not sure. On the one hand, it seems overly specific to need a string escaped for JSON in a setting where it isn't just part of an object that itself is being serialized to JSON, so I'd wonder what the benefit to going through the trouble of including such a method in the core library would be (particularly when it is custom-implemented easily enough by the few people who do actually need it). On the other hand, there are a fair amount of other methods that I would've thought too specific to put in the core library as well, so this one may exist somewhere too. Who knows?